# Android Developer Studio - Discrepancy between board and emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

**Important Notice**
This is a project that fell from the sky, and although I'm a seasoned iOS dev, i have never touched anything android related...

**Question**
When i open my "StartScreenActivity.xml", android developer studio opens up a "drag-and-drop" kind of editor where I see a bunch of buttons, ribbons, and other ui elements. This board also allows me to see how it would look like in other devices (Nexus 4, 5, 10, etc...) but since im a beginner, i'm just working with Nexus 4 for now, and it looks pretty good.
When I hit "Run" the Nexus 4 emulator launches but a lot of the UI elements presented on the design-board are not presented on the emulator!!! other elements also are different... What am I doing wrong here? How should I debug this issue?

**Deatils**

- I think I'm looking at the right xml because there's a StartScreenActivity.java file with a `@EActivity(R.layout.StartScreenActivity)`, and if i put a breakpoint on the `onCreate` method, it stops...
- I don't see any code that could indicate that the buttons are begin rotated, moved or hidden at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was the `AndroidAnnotations`. While migrating the project to Android Developer Studio the pack was lost...